# Migration Issue to Java 11 from legacy code

Tags: java, java-9, java-11

We are migrating our old code, in fact pretty old to Java 11. I am facing issues while compiling one of the classes. The sample code is:

```
package XXXX;

import java.lang.ref.*;
import sun.security.action.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.io.*;

class Converters
{
    private static Object lock;
    private static String converterPackageName;
    private static String defaultEncoding;
    public static final int BYTE_TO_CHAR = 0;
    public static final int CHAR_TO_BYTE = 1;
    private static final String[] converterPrefix;
    private static SoftReference[] classCache;
    static /* synthetic */ Class class$sun$io$Converters;

    private static String getConverterPackageName() {
        final String converterPackageName = Converters.converterPackageName;
        if (converterPackageName != null) {
            return converterPackageName;
        }
        String converterPackageName2 = AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction<String>)new GetPropertyAction("file.encoding.pkg"));
        if (converterPackageName2 != null) {
            Converters.converterPackageName = converterPackageName2;
        }
        else {
            converterPackageName2 = "sun.io";
        }
        return converterPackageName2;
    }

    private static Class getConverterClass(final int n, final String s) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String aliasName = null;
        if (!s.equals("ISO8859_1")) {
            if (s.equals("8859_1")) {
                aliasName = "ISO8859_1";
            }
            else if (s.equals("ISO8859-1")) {
                aliasName = "ISO8859_1";
            }
            else if (s.equals("646")) {
                aliasName = "ASCII";
            }
            else {
                aliasName = CharacterEncoding.aliasName(s);
            }
        }
        if (aliasName == null) {
            aliasName = s;
        }
        try {
            return Class.forName(getConverterPackageName() + "." + Converters.converterPrefix[n] + aliasName);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new UnsupportedEncodingException(aliasName);
        }
    }

    private static Object newConverter(final String s, final Class clazz) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        try {
            return clazz.newInstance();
        }
        catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            throw new UnsupportedEncodingException(s);
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException ex2) {
            throw new UnsupportedEncodingException(s);
        }
    }

    static Object newConverter(final int n, final String s) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        final Class converterClass;
        synchronized (Converters.lock) {
            converterClass = getConverterClass(n, s);
        }
        return newConverter(s, converterClass);
    }

    private static Class getDefaultConverterClass(final int n) {
        boolean b = false;
        final SoftReference softReference = Converters.classCache[n];
        if (softReference != null) {
            final Class clazz = softReference.get();
            if (clazz != null) {
                return clazz;
            }
            Converters.classCache[n] = null;
        }
        String defaultEncoding = Converters.defaultEncoding;
        if (Converters.defaultEncoding != null) {
            b = true;
        }
        else {
            defaultEncoding = AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction<String>)new GetPropertyAction("file.encoding"));
            if (defaultEncoding != null) {
                Converters.defaultEncoding = defaultEncoding;
                b = true;
            }
            else {
                defaultEncoding = "ISO8859_1";
            }
        }
        Class clazz2;
        try {
            clazz2 = getConverterClass(n, defaultEncoding);
            if (b) {
                Converters.classCache[n] = new SoftReference(clazz2);
            }
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            try {
                clazz2 = getConverterClass(n, "ISO8859_1");
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex2) {
                throw new InternalError("Cannot find default " + Converters.converterPrefix[n] + " converter class");
            }
        }
        return clazz2;
    }

    static Object newDefaultConverter(final int n) {
        final Class defaultConverterClass;
        synchronized (Converters.lock) {
            defaultConverterClass = getDefaultConverterClass(n);
        }
        try {
            return newConverter("", defaultConverterClass);
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            throw new InternalError("Cannot instantiate default converter class " + defaultConverterClass.getName());
        }
    }

    static /* synthetic */ Class class$(final String s) {
        try {
            return Class.forName(s);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new NoClassDefFoundError(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    static {
        Converters.lock = ((Converters.class$sun$io$Converters == null) ? (Converters.class$sun$io$Converters = class$("sun.io.Converters")) : Converters.class$sun$io$Converters);
        Converters.converterPackageName = null;
        Converters.defaultEncoding = null;
        converterPrefix = new String[] { "ByteToChar", "CharToByte" };
        Converters.classCache = new SoftReference[2];
    }
}
```

While compiling it using `javac Converter.java`, I am getting the error below:

```
import sun.security.action.*;
                   ^
  (package sun.security.action is declared in module java.base, which does not export it to the unnamed module)
Converters.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
                aliasName = CharacterEncoding.aliasName(s);
                            ^
  symbol:   variable CharacterEncoding
  location: class Converters
Converters.java:85: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Class
            final Class clazz = softReference.get();
                                                 ^
Note: Converters.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Converters.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 errors
```

I tried to export this using `--add--export
java.base/sun.security=All-UNNAMED`, it's still throwing the error.

Any help? Also would like to know is there any other way to remove this old legacy code with new one.

Comment: This is not your legacy code, this is the result of running a decompiler on a JDK class. It's extremely strange that you need to compile this code as part of your system.

Comment: sun.* packages are JVM internal and have never been meant for use by implementation classes. If you've not been bitten by that before, you just got extremely lucky.

Comment: Ohh I see, It was bundled in a jar. Is there any alternate of using it in new Libraries

Comment: Of course, there is an alternative. Don’t use that code. Once we know what you actually want to do, we can tell you, how to do it. Java has easy-to-use charset conversion methods since version 1.1.

Comment: CharacterEncoding was located in `sun.io` and is deprecated since Java 1.6 (and now removed). Use `java.nio.charset` instead.

Comment: There use to be a very weird code not sure in which era and bundled into jars , which I noticed now.  ByteToCharRoman8 converter = new ByteToCharRoman8(); and calling converter.convert(...). The problem is due to this and all its dependencies are of Java 2 , I guess.

Comment: Not sure if there was any standard library like that ByteToCharRoman8  in any of Java earlier version which converts the byte. Is there any standard library available now?

Comment: Robert is right. The charset API was added in Java SE 1.4 and developers have had 17 years to move away from the legacy sun.io converters.

Answer (score 5):

Since Java 9, most of the JDK's internal APIs [are inaccessible at compile time](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/260) (and in the future, they will be inaccessible at run time too). `sun.security.action` is an internal package so you should avoid using it. In your case, you can simply remove `new GetPropertyAction("file.encoding.pkg")` and replace it with a lambda:

```
AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction<Object>) () -> System.getProperty("prop"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, really appreciate. But I am looking forward to replace the old self made jar. Is there amy better way to replace this.

Comment: final ByteToCharRoman8 converter = new ByteToCharRoman8();

            final byte[] ba = new byte[] { b };
            final char[] ca = new char[1];

            converter.convert(ba, 0, 1, ca, 0, 1);

Comment: ByteToCharRoman8 is a pretty old library of java which was bundled in a self made jar by some team long back.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out, these are internal classes that should not be used directly. If refactoring is out of scope, you should use `--add-export` and this should work!

Your `--add-export` argument is wrong. You need to use the correct package to export (`sun.security.action` in your case) and the name of your module (ALL-UNNAMED if you don't use modules, all in **capital letters** !).

So this should be `--add-exports java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED`

From the documentation of javac :

> --add-exports module/package=other-module(,other-module)* Specifies a package to be considered as exported from its defining module to
>   additional modules or to all unnamed modules when the value of
>   other-module is ALL-UNNAMED.

Answer (score 0):

There's example file for java 17:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.readcrl_2</groupId>
    <artifactId>ReadCRL_2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--add-exports</arg>
            <arg>java.base/sun.security.x509=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>            
          </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.70</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.70</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>config/sun_checks.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    
</project>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).